# Как суммировать полученные цифры результата сложения в Java

Tags: java, android

Есть, например, набор чисел, исходящих из даты: `10051993`. Нужно сделать несколько этапов:

1. Как сложить эти числа по отдельности, то есть `1+0+0+5+1+9+9+3 = 28`;
2. Как разделить результат на отдельные цифры и суммировать их, то есть `2+8 = 10`.

Comment: А Вы как-то уже попробовали?